# Getting error message using EXT:recaptcha and EXT:form in Typo3 8.7.9 in a custom template

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

im using the new EXT:form extension from Typo3 8. I put it in my own extension folder so i made a custom template for it. This works fine until the point i want to integrate Google recaptcha into it.

I want to use the EXT:recaptcha for this:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/recaptcha/Index.html

In the sample EXT:form layout the recaptcha works without problems. But when im switching back to my layout i get the following error message:

> Oops, an error occurred! The validator preset identified by
>   "Recaptcha" could not be found, or the implementationClassName was not
>   specified.

What i have to do? Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old, you probably found the solution already.

I'm quite sure you did not include the static template. After adding the recaptcha template to my root template the validator was available.